# if present tense + subject would/will V

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

> a. If Mary tells you the details of her job, she **would** be failing in her duty.

> b. If Mary tells you the details of her job, she **will** be failing in her duty.

I know the sentence does not belong to any of the traditional conditional sentence types, but I have seen this sort of pairing (present tense in the if-clause and "would  in the main clause) before. I'd like to know if a is correct, and if so, how it differs from b.

Answer (score -2):

if present tense + subject would/will.

---

Examples - **a.** If Mary tells you the details of her job, she **would** be failing in her dut**ies**.--v--b. If Mary tells you the details of her job, she **will** be failing in her dut**ies**.

> Q. I have seen this sort of pairing (present tense in the if-clause and "would in the main clause) before. I'd like to know if a is correct, and if so, how it differs from b.

---

**A. Yes, "a." is correct as "would" is used as a conditional verb.**

> **Would is a past tense form of will**. It is also **a conditional verb that indicates an action that would happen under certain conditions**.

> ***Conditional verbs are used to create conditional sentences**, which express hypothetical or unlikely situations. **Conditional verbs can be used in the past, present, or future tense**, and auxiliary verbs like can/could, will/would, and may/might are important in forming conditionals.*

Example

> **If I had enough money, I would travel around the world.** Ref [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-verbs/)

**"b." is incorrect** in this case; as a modal verb is usually followed by the root form of a verb. If we rewrite "b.2 If Mary tells you the details of her job, she **will** fail in her duties. The sentence now has a different meaning or implication may be a better way to explain it. The use of will now indicates something in the far future. If it was to happen in the "near" future we would not use "will" but "going to" [Expressing a Future Action: When To Use “Will” And “Going To”](http://gonaturalenglish.com/).

***For b. to be correct** we would have to write*

***If Mary tells you the details of her job, she is "going to" be failing in her duties***.

> **Will** can be a present tense verb that means to cause something to happen through force of desire. **It can also be a modal auxiliary verb in various tenses.**

> **USE WILL FOR A FAR FURTHER FUTURE ACTION**
> One important detail about “WILL” is that it is most often used to discuss things or situations that may take a long time to happen.

WHEN TO USE “GOING TO”
One huge difference in using GOING TO versus WILL, is that you **use GOING TO when the action was already decided on** even before speaking of it.

Comment: It might be helpful to discuss the difference between "If Mary **tells** you the details of her job, she **would** be failing in her dutyies" and "If Mary **told** you the details of her job, she **would** be failing in her duties."

Comment: @Apollyon, yes I considered that but it rather defeats the question regarding the present tense and the  past tense inferred by **would** (which actually is not a past tense). Therefore I decided to leave the present tense "as is". Note also it would be come "If Mary had told you the details of her job, she would have failed in her duties."

Comment: If sentence b is really incorrect, I am not sure if the reason is  "a modal verb is usually followed by the root form of a verb." After all, there are sentences like "If you quit your job, you **will be doing** something stupid."

Comment: I disagree that (b) is incorrect. I would say "If she told you, she would..." and "If she tells you, she will...".

Comment: @KateBunting Would you like to write a reply?

Comment: @Kate Bunting; I would agree that use, like this, is relatively common but I would still say it is incorrect. Will here is relating to an action - failing - However, "Will" is used "to express actions that are far into the future" However the use of failing which is happening now negates this use. However fail would not. I will get married someday.”  -  If Mary tells you the details of her job, she is going to be failing in her duties.

Comment: I would interpret this as 'present as future'. "If Mary tells you (at some future time), she will fail."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Agreed which brings us back to my root form of the verb and the different implication. As we would use "going to" not "will" for a short term in the future. This is where my deduction that answer b is incorrect stems from. https://www.gonaturalenglish.com/expressing-a-future-action-will-and-going-to/

Comment: @Kate Bunting Could you put up the clause: "...,she would be failing in her duties" in other words (changing "failing", specifically), please? I don't grip the meaning of the pattern precisely (whether she will just flop in her duty or her telling someone the details  demonstrates that she is uncapable of carrying out the duty by herself and asks that someone may help her, i.e. "If Mary is telling you the details of her job it would be that she is failing in her job (and she is implying your help) or... I don't know).

Comment: :@Eugene - I would understand Apollyon's sentence as meaning that Mary's job is secret and it is her duty not to speak about it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks a lot. Are there any cases possible when the construction "would+be+Ving" refers to the present time? For example: "Oh, this would be interesting" or "Oh, she would be failing in her duty (it is being manifested by her crushed look)?